# Change message box buttons' name in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, messagebox

I would like to change the text in the buttons of the message box that appears in my app.
So for example, instead of 'yes' I want to use 'Camera' and instead of 'no' I want to use 'Media library'..Anyone got any idea??

this is how far I got..

DialogResult dlgResult=MessageBox.Show("Inport photo","Select from where to import photo",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,MessageBoxIcon.None);

I am very much struggling with it, any ideas are welcomed. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can't change the default buttons of MessageBox. Better, you can `Microsoft Phone Toolkit` in this you can create Custom Message Box with your desired left and right buttons and also you can set the function what if those buttons are clicked.

To download NuGet, tap here. and in your project press left click and then Manage NuGet packages and search Microsoft Phone Toolkit and once you have found the package simply press install and then use my below code.

```
CustomMessageBox messageBox = new CustomMessageBox()
        {
            Title = "Inport photo", //your title
            Message = "Select from where to import photo", //your message
            RightButtonContent = "Yes", // you can change this right and left button content
            LeftButtonContent = "No",
        };

        messageBox.Dismissed += (s2, e2) =>
        {
            switch (e2.Result)
            {
                case CustomMessageBoxResult.RightButton:
                    //here your function for right button
                break;
                case CustomMessageBoxResult.LeftButton:
                    //here your function for left button
                break;
                default:
                break;
            }
        };

        messageBox.Show();
```

Answer (score 2):

Default Silverlight API does not allow you to do this, however XNA API does. See following link:

http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/delivering-message-using